# Weird errors adding iframe to a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, iframe

I tried to add an iframe to one of my clients' pages, and am getting all sorts of weird errors:

```
App Temporarily Unavailable
Parse errors:
FBML Error (line 28): illegal tag "body" under "fb:tab-position"
FBML Error (line 125): illegal tag "object" under "fb:tab-position"
FBML Error (line 126): illegal tag "param" under "fb:tab-position"
Runtime errors:
HTML error while rendering tag "link": There is a hard limit of 2 css link tags on profile tabs in order to remain under the IE 31 tag limit.
HTML error while rendering tag "link": There is a hard limit of 2 css link tags on profile tabs in order to remain under the IE 31 tag limit.
```

The page/tab is [here](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Elevation-Events/189638366366?sk=app_134166499967654).

I'm trying to iframe `http(s)://www.elevation-events.com/fb/`. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be an old app with the FBML type still active.  You should see a setting somewhere in the Facebook developer settings to change the app type from FBML to iframe.

The errors you're seeing are that some of the basic tags like body weren't allowed using FBML.

Comment: That's what I thought, but it's already been set to iFrame... any way to get someone over at facebook to have a look-see in the back-end if this is somehow not being set properly?